# magento2 payment form after order complete

Tags: magento2

I have successfully created a module from

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/base-integration/integration-intro.html

It's working and shown in checkout page.

The question: How do I add a button called **"Pay"** after order is complete, which will contain a payment provider form or open a popup with new order data such as orderId and etc..?